# Uploading image to Firebase using React, Axios & Busboy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, busboy

Having a hell of a time with this one.

I am building a full stack app very similar to the social-ape project on the YouTube channel Classsed. I have a React component grabbing a file from an input, using axios to post it to my server.

React submit handler:

```
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const image = event.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", image, image.name);

    axios
      .post(
        `http://localhost:5000/album/${this.state.id}/editAlbumCover`,
        formData
      )
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

Express Route

```
exports.editAlbumCover = (req, res) => {
  const BusBoy = require("busboy");
  const path = require("path");
  const os = require("os");
  const fs = require("fs");

  const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });
  console.log("Busboy.init");
  let imageFileName;
  let imageToBeUploaded = {};

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    console.log("Busboy.on");
    if (mimetype !== "image/jpeg" && mimetype !== "image/png") {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error: "Wrong file type. Please upload a JPEG or PNG file." });
    }

    const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[filename.split(".").length - 1];
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(
      Math.random() * 1000000000
    )}.${imageExtension}`;
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
    imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
  });

  busboy.on("finish", () => {
    console.log("Busboy.finish");
    admin
      .storage()
      .bucket(config.storageBucket)
      .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype,
          },
        },
      })
      .then(() => {
        const albumCover = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
        return db.doc(`/albums/${req.params.id}`).update({ albumCover });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return res.json({ message: "Image uploaded successfully" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
      });
  });
```

The FormData.append in the submit handler works because I can use .forEach to log the single entry in there before posting with Axios.

The express route is not triggering the busboy.on("file") callback, but everything else it triggered. Upon submission I get this error in my server console:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

Console logging ImageToBeUploaded shows that nothing ever gets added to that object. If I use axios to post some random string to the same route I can log it out from the req. The code is almost identical to the project I coded along to on YouTube so I'm really not sure why busboy.on isn't being triggered.